# how to add/remove the connector in Pulsar in rest api?

Tags: debezium, apache-pulsar

I am using Pulsar IO with support for the Debezium source connectors to get stream changes from your databases.

From the documentation, it is clear how  to connect to MYSQL,

```
$ bin/pulsar-admin source localrun  --sourceConfigFile debezium-mysql-source-config.yaml
```

to monitor the connector

```
bin/pulsar-admin functions getstatus \
    --tenant <tenant> \
    --namespace <namespace> \
    --name <connector-name>
```

But I can't see how to remove the connector in Pulsar?

And any rest API to add/remove connector?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the connector using the delete command, i.e.

```
bin/pulsar-admin source delete \
    --tenant <tenant> \
    --namespace <namespace> \
    --name <connector-name>
```

For more information, you can refer to the Pulsar documentation
http://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/reference-connector-admin/#delete